# A question on a double integral: $\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin y}{\pi-y}\,dy\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin y}{\pi-y}\,dy\,dx = \large{?}$$

For this question,I changed the order of limits and then tried the substitution for $(\pi-y)$ as $t$  and tried integration by parts but I couldn't proceed further as the answer was getting really complicated and this is a numerical answer type question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $I$ be the integral given by

$$I=\int_0^\pi \int_0^x \frac{\sin(y)}{\pi-y}\,dy\,dx$$

---

> **ASIDE:**
>
> Since $\left|\frac{\sin(y)}{\pi-y}\right|\le 1$, $\iint\left|\frac{\sin(y)}{\pi-y}\right|\,d(x,y)<\infty$.  Therefore, [Fubini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini.27s_theorem_for_integrable_functions) guarantees that the double integral and both iterated integrals are equal.

---

Changing the order of integration reveals

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^\pi \int_y^\pi \frac{\sin(y)}{\pi-y}\,dx\,dy\\\\
&=\int_0^\pi \sin(y)\,dy\\\\
&=2
\end{align}$$

Comment: can you explain how you changed the order of integration?

Comment: Sure.  The domain of integration is a triangular region with vertices at $(0,0)$, $(\pi,0)$, and $(\pi,\pi)$.  So, this can be described as the region $x\in [0,\pi] \times y\in [0,x]$ OR $y\in [0,\pi] \times x\in [y,\pi]$.

Comment: I would advise @NAJMAASHRAF to take a look at Fubini's theorem! If it may help

Comment: @FourierTransform And since the integrand has a removable discontinuity at $\pi$, the interchange of integrals is legitimate.